# Basic question about topology of $2$-dimensional manifolds

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds, surfaces, geometric-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $M^2$ be a smooth $2$-dimensional and  simply connected manifold without boundary. Let $\Omega \subseteq M$ be an open and path-connected subset of $M$. Let us assume that each connected component of $\partial \Omega$ is contractible. Is $\Omega$ simply connected? 
I believe the answer is yes, but I haven't thought about those topological questions in a very long time. Any help will be very much apreciated.

**EDIT**: My intuition is that if by contradiction $\Omega$ is not simply connected, then I can find a loop in $\Omega$ wich is not homotopically trivial (in $\Omega$) but it is trivial in $M$. Somehow, for this to happen, there must be a loop in $\partial \Omega$, but this is not the case, by hypotesis.

**SECOND EDIT** As pointed out in the comments, the answer might be "no" if I don't assume something more on $\partial \Omega$. Actually, in the case I am interested in, $\partial \Omega$ is a union of at most countably many properly embedded 1-dim manifolds.

Comment: If $M^2=\mathbb{R}^2$, then $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \{0\}$ is open and path-connected and $\partial \Omega = \{0\}$ is contractible, while $\Omega$ is not simply connected. Is some hypothesis missing?

Comment: Do you assume that the boundary of $\Omega$ is locally connected? Otherwise, the statement is false. If you assume that the boundary of $\Omega$ is a 1-dimensional submanifold then you can prove the claim using van Kampen's theorem (plus some extra work).

Comment: Thanks @AloizioMacedo for your counterexample. 
Actually, Mishe Kohan is right. In the case I am interested in, the boundary a union of at most countably  many 1-dimensional and properly embedded manifolds. Ok, I'll try to use that theorem and see where can I end up.